# Is it possible to use yml files in i18next?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

Is it possible to use yml files in i18next?
How can I configure my project to accept yml instead of json?

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import ENUS from "./locales/en_US.yml";

const initLng = navigator.language;
console.log(initLng);
console.log(ENUS);
const resources = {
  'en-US': ENUS
};
i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: initLng,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can convert the YAML file to json.
i.e. by using a module like: https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml

btw: the i18next-fs-backend plugin for example is doing this: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-fs-backend
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[next-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next) supports yml files. Therefor, use the config option `localeExtension` to change the expected file extension to `yml`:

Example:

```
// next-i18next.config.js
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        locales: ['en', 'de'],
        localeExtension: 'yml'
    }
}
```

This works also for SSG as demonstrated by this [example project](https://github.com/i18next/next-language-detector/tree/main/examples/basic). The example project uses `json` by default, but with `localeExtension` it can be changed to `yml` without installing any additional packages.

The `localeExtension` option was implemented with pull request [#302](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/pull/302).

Comment: next-i18next uses i18next-fs-backend behind the scenes